# CervoNeue font issue

Tags: html, css, sass, fonts, font-face

I have a question regarding the CervoNeue font.
For some reason when the font looks like this on a website (as you can see there are some letters that look weird, and this only happens if the screen size is over 1024px):
[image]

I tried the font locally and it looks like it should.

I tried declaring it in multiple ways:

a)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "CervoNeue-Light";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url('../fonts/CervoNeueLightNeue.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/CervoNeueLightNeue.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "CervoNeue-Regular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/CervoNeueRegularNeue.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/CervoNeueRegularNeue.woff') format('woff');
}
```

b)

```
/* CervoNeue Light */
@font-face {
  font-family: "CervoNeue";
  src: url('../fonts/cervo-neue/CervoNeueLightNeue.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/cervo-neue/CervoNeueLightNeue.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "CervoNeue";
  src: url('../fonts/cervo-neue/CervoNeueLightNeueItalic.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/cervo-neue/CervoNeueLightNeueItalic.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}

/* CervoNeue Regular */
@font-face {
  font-family: "CervoNeue";
  src: url('../fonts/cervo-neue/CervoNeueRegularNeue.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/cervo-neue/CervoNeueRegularNeue.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I also noticed something odd in the Network tab:
[image]

The preview of the font is weird, compared to how it should look. Locally, the preview is just not available.

The `font-face` declarations also seem to appear as they should inside the final `css` file.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!